# Auto Format your Code on Save in Dreamweaver

Tags: html, formatting, dreamweaver, code-formatting

I saw the formatting option for dreamweaver is

Commands > Apply Formatting
Commands > Clean up HTML

Is there is a way to apply formatting on save automatically instead of applying the options everytime.
Whenever i save from the dreamweaver (I manually click the formatting). I want to make auto formatting on save (CTRL+S).

Any Suggestion would be great.

Thanks,
vicky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please click on "edit" -> then keyboard shortcuts. It`s straight forward from there. Just select the command from the list, and press the + button.

You will need to create a duplicate set, then select it again from the list. And finally set a keyboard shortcut!

Now, before saving, press the shortcut you just created!